# Book recommendations for English learners

Tags: discussion, resource-request

I'm looking for a book that shows in the majority of the chronological learn (if possible) about the English topics. The ideal is explanatory texts over exercises to learn.

For example, Basic English Tenses in order or Conditional Sentences.

Comment: Maybe something in the "for dummies" series?

Comment: I'm a learner myself, I started with _Longman Student Grammar of Spoken and Written English_ (Biber et al., 1999) for the basic. You also need a usage guide (eg. _Practical English Usage_, Swan 1980 or _Webster's Dictionary of English Usage_, 1989). When I understood the basic, I started reading highly technical reference grammars such as _A Student's Introduction to English Grammar_ (Huddleston & Pullum, 2004) and _The Cambridge Grammar of The English Language_ (Huddleston & Pullum, 2002).